# what is the time complexity of this code snippet?

Tags: time-complexity

I am using this algorithm in my program :

```
for( i=0 ; i<N ; i++ )

  for( j=i+1 ; j<N+1 ; j++ )

     for( k=0 ; k<i ; k++ )

          doWork();
```

Can anyone help me find the time complexity of this snippet ?
I guess for the first two loops it is

```
N*(N+1)/2
```

right ? what about the three loops all together?

Comment: In a simple analysis you would leave out any constant multipliers and summands, which would indeed leave you with O(N³). In this special case it might be interesting to an amortized runtime analysis, which is a lot more difficult to do. ;) So make sure you *really* need to know it this exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim Meyer to correct me:

Simple equation gives for (N= 0,1,2,3,4,5,6, 7, 8 ...) following series: 0, 0, 1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, 84 ... , which is resolved with following formula:

```
u(n) = (n - 1)n(n + 1)/6
```

So it will have **O((N - 1)N(N + 1)/6)** time complexity, which can be simplified to **O(N^3)**

Comment: It's not 100% correct because for N = 0 and N = 1 `doWork()` will not be called. Then for N = 2,3,4,5,.. the series will be 1,4,10,20,.. So it would be `(N-1)*(N)*(N+1)/6` which is `(N^3-N)/6`. Usually you simplify that to O(N^3) as this is the dominating factor in that equation

Comment: @Tim Meyer - thank you for your correction, I've updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you can do the following:

[image]